# How to use gif images in android?

Tags: android, image, user-interface, android-layout, gif

I want to fetch the image from server through web service and displayed in my app. So how to use Gif images directly from drawable or from web service.

Comment: i would suggest you to use glide library

Comment: `ImageView` can display GIF files just fine AFAIK. What it cannot do is display animated GIFs, and for that, there are [many libraries](https://android-arsenal.com/search?q=gif).

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion webview is best for gif image to load.  You can do it easily by  extending the WebView.

Step-1 //create a class

```
public class MyGifView extends WebView {
    public MyGifView(Context context, String path) {
        super(context);
        loadUrl(path);
    }
}
```

Step-2
In your Activity

```
         //If it is an url
        MyGifView myGifView = new MyGifView(this, "http://www.picgifs.com/animal-graphics/animal-graphics/kangaroo/animal-graphics-kangaroo-363368.gif");
            //If gif image in assets folder
        MyGifView view = new MyGifView(this, "file:///android_asset/mygif.gif"); 

         //If gif image in drawable folder
        MyGifView view = new MyGifView(this, "file:///android_res/drawable/mygif.gif"); 
        yourlayout.addView(myGifView); //add to desire layout 
                OR
        setContentView(myGifView);   //add to content view
```